# What is the best approach to rig thin mesh like this - claw?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

[image]

Approaches I can think of:

1. Use wire bone
2. Make the bone smaller
3. Weight paint

Comment: Hello, make the bones smaller seems like a good idea, no?

Comment: This is very much asking for opinion-based answers I think... there is no objectively best way. Making the bones smaller - yeah, if you want to. Does not seem bad. Weight-paint? You can do that and it will work if done correctly, but I guess the claws should be rigid and not deform, so they can simply be parented to the bone. However it seems like the blade itself is a part of the rest of the mesh, so you need weight paint in order to move it.